# On one android handset, it is taking image from different folders

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android app I am using `mdpi`, `hdpi` and `xdpi` resource folder and I have placed different sets of images on the basis of resolution in these folders for example:

mdpi contain images of 320x 480 resolution
hdpi contain images of 480 x 800 resolution
xhdpi contain images of 720 x 1280 resolution

When I load the application in Samsung S3, for tabs in `tabwidget`, it takes images from `xhdpi` folder and for the buttons it take images from `hdpi` folder.

Comment: This can happen only if your button images are not in xhdpi. BTW, resolutions and dpi are not exactly related.

Comment: Have you put button image in all folder of drawable?

Comment: I have put all the images in all the three folders.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this once..

place 320 X 480 images in drawable-mdpi,

place 480 X 800 images in drawable-hdpi,

place 720 X 1280 images in drawable-xlarge-v11.

Once check with name conflict of images also. Use same image names in all folders.

Answer (score 0):

Put the images for buttons in x-hdpi folder. When android don't images in x-hdpi folder, it goes to find it in next lower resolution folder.

But the either case of this is not true. When android requires any image from hdpi folder, it doesn't take images from x-hdpi folder. Infact it will crash if the images are not present in lower resolution other than hdpi.